# How do I pass lists (and other information) from the parent models global variable to it's child's model global variable in Netlogo's LevelSpace

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently building a multi level ABM using Levelspace. I am also using the extrawidget extension as a frontend GUI for entering and capturing user information. The extrawidget GUI is a stand alone Netlogo model and serves as the parent model in Levelspace. Some of the captured information is stored as lists in the parent models global variables.

I am trying pass the content of the extrawidget parent model global variables (particularly the lists) to the child model's global variables. I cannot seem to find a way to accomplish this. I've tried "ls:let" in conjunction with "ls:ask" to set the child models global variable but that did not work. I used "ls:assign" but that was unsuccessful also.

I believe some kind of reporter in both the parent and child model may be the answer but I am unable to determine how to code something like that.

Could someone please assist me in solving this problem.

Thanks

Rudy

--------------------------------------------------------Follow-Up---------------------------------------------------

I discovered that ls:assign did work, "clear-all" in the child model's setup command wiped out the information in global variables. I removed the "clear-all" and can see the lists in monitors I added for the global variables but even though the lists are there I'm still getting this error message when the child model attempts to run "setup"

" Extension exception: Model 0 (Scaled Agile Simulator1.nlogo) encountered an error: ITEM expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.
error while observer running LS:ASK
called by procedure SETUP
called by procedure __EVALUATOR"

I have included the child model setup code below:

```
to setup
  ls:reset
  ;clear-all
  
  let n length TotEpics
  foreach n-values n [ [i] -> i ] [ [i] ->
    create-Epics 1 [
      setxy -20 20
      set label item i TotEpics
      set Complex item i EpicCmplx
      set Stories item i EpicStories
      set ETime [ ]
      set Tasks1 EpicTasks1
      set Tasks2 EpicTasks2
      set Tasks3 EpicTasks3
      set Tasks4 EpicTasks4
      set shape "box"
      set size 8
    ]
  ]
  let o length ScrumTN1
  foreach n-values o [ [i] -> i ] [ [i] ->
    create-Scrum-Teams 1 [
      set label item i ScrumTN1
      set shape "Scrum"
      set color color
      set Members item i ScrumTM1
      set Strat item i ScrumStrt1
      set AsgnEpic item i ScrmEpic1
      set S-Stories 0
      set Cost item i ScrumCst1
      set Value [  ]
      set Time [ ]
      set S-Story-Size 0
      set xcor -16
      set ycor 12 + i * -7
      set size 4.5
      ls:create-interactive-models 1 "Problem_Solving_in_Networks WIP.nlogo"
      set model-id last ls:models
      ls:hide model-id
    ]
  ]
  let b length ScrumTN2
   foreach n-values b [ [i] -> i ] [ [i] ->
    create-Scrum-Teams 1 [
      set label item i ScrumTN2
      set shape "Scrum"
      set color item i Color1
      set Members item i ScrumTM2
      set Strat item i ScrumStrt2
      set AsgnEpic item i ScrmEpic2
      set S-Stories 0
      set Cost item i ScrumCst2
      set Value [  ]
      set Time [ ]
      set S-Story-Size 0
      set xcor -4.5
      set ycor 12 + i * -7
      set size 4.5
      ls:create-interactive-models 1 "Problem_Solving_in_Networks WIP.nlogo"
      set model-id last ls:models
      ls:hide model-id
   ]
 ]

  let p length KanbanTN3
  foreach n-values p [ [i] -> i ] [ [i] ->
    create-Kanban-Teams 1  [
      set label item i KanbanTN3
      set shape "Kanban"
      set color color
      set xcor -18 + i * 9
      set ycor -20
      set size 4.5
      ls:create-interactive-models 1 "Kanban3_v5_2.nlogo"
      set model-id last ls:models
      ls:hide model-id
    ]
 ]
```

All the "variables" in "set variable-name item i variables" are lists so I'm not expecting to see the error message stating "ITEM expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead"

Anyone have any insights?

Thanks

Rudy

---------------------------------------------Please Disregard until further notice-----------------------------------

I've discovered some missing code in my setup command causing this "ERROR". Please disregard my question. If I run into any serious roadblocks I'll reach out.

Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you found solutions to your problems!  For future reference, if you do find a solution, it's fine to update your post to say so (or leave a comment or an answer), but if you then run into a different problem you should open a new question for it rather than re-using the original question.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, will do